# ScrollViewReader is not working and building is pretty slow

Tags: swiftui

I couldn't figure out why it is not working my ScrollViewReader below my code. Please help me figure out the issue. I want to pass my zolyric.number into scrollToIndex and that scrollToIndex will set the number that I want to scroll in my HymnLyrics(). Also, although I couldn't find the error, the building is pretty slow.

Here ZolaiTitles() is the same list just sorting the song titles algebraically and HymnLyrics() is the one to display in the canvas.

```
struct ZolaiTitles: View {
    
    @AppStorage("scrollToIndex") var scrollToIndex: Int?
    
    
    @EnvironmentObject var tappingSwitches: TapToggle
    
    let zoLyrics: [Lyric] = LyricList.hymnLa.sorted { lhs, rhs in
        return lhs.zoTitle < rhs.zoTitle
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(zoLyrics, id: \.id) { zoLyric in
                VStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        
                        //if let lyricNum = String(zoLyric) {
                        scrollToIndex = zoLyric.number // zolyric.number is already an interger.
                        //}

                        self.tappingSwitches.isHymnTapped.toggle()
                        
                    }, label: {
                        HStack {
                            Text(zoLyric.zoTitle)
                                .foregroundColor(Color("bTextColor"))
                                .lineLimit(1)
                                .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)

                            Spacer()
                            Text("\(zoLyric.number)")
                                .foregroundColor(Color("bTextColor"))
                        }
                    })
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                .padding([.leading, .bottom, .trailing])
            }
        }
    }
}


struct HymnLyrics: View {
    
    @AppStorage("scrollToIndex") var scrollToIndex: Int = 1
    
    var lyrics: [Lyric] = LyricList.hymnLa
    @AppStorage("fontSizeIndex") var fontSizeIndex = Int("Medium") ?? 18
    @AppStorage("fontIndex") var fontIndex: String = ""
    @AppStorage("showHVNumbers") var showHVNumbers: Bool = true
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            List(lyrics, id: \.id) { lyric in
                
                VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
                    
                    Text("\(lyric.number)")
                        .padding()
                        .multilineTextAlignment(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.leading/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                        .id(lyric.number)
                        
                    
                    VStack {
                        VStack {
                            Text(lyric.zoTitle)
                                .font(.title2)
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                                .foregroundColor(.primary)
                                .autocapitalization(.allCharacters)
                            
                            Text(lyric.engTitle)
                                .font(.title3)
                                .fontWeight(.medium)
                                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                                .italic()
                                
                        }
                        // Don't use Padding here!
                        
                    }
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    
                    HStack {
                        Text(lyric.key)
                            .italic()
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                        Text(lyric.musicStyle)
                    }
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    .padding(.vertical)
                }
                //.id(lyric.number)

            }
            .onChange(of: scrollToIndex, perform: { value in
                proxy.scrollTo(value, anchor: .top)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I’m pretty sure ScrollViewReader needs to be directly inside a ScrollView, **not** somewhere further down the hierarchy

Comment: Thanks @aheze, it works after implementing under a scrollview and change my list into foreach loop. But the building took quite a while. Is there something wrong with my code. Also the view doesn't stick on the page. The page always starts from the beginning.

Comment: `onChange` only will be called when `scrollToIndex` is changed. When your app starts it's not calling it, use `onApeear` to scroll to value saved with `AppStorage`

Comment: @aheze: ScrollViewReader needs to be directly ***outside*** a ScrollView

Comment: @soundflix good catch, I missed that